# Return the length of the String that comes first lexicographically

Tags: java, lexicographic

I am trying pass two strings to a function and I want to return the length of the string that comes first lexicographically.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
public static int problem4(String s, String t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() &&
            i < t.length(); i++) {
        if ((int) s.charAt(i) ==
                (int) t.charAt(i)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            return (int) s.length() -
                    (int) t.length();
        }
    }

    if (s.length() < t.length()) {
        return (s.length() - t.length());
    } else if (s.length() > t.length()) {
        return (s.length() - t.length());
    }

    // If none of the above conditions is true, 
    // it implies both the strings are equal 
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt at solving the problem? We are not going to do your job for you, but we can help you if you have tried something and it doesn't work as expected. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Remember to be kind even if people tend to think that SO is a "do the job for me" kind of site.

Comment: sorry for asking a poor question, it was my first time using the site. I will provide my work next time. Sorry

Comment: `return s.compareTo(t) == -1 ? s.length() : s.compareTo(t) == 1  ? t.length() : s.length();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set them into an array, and use Arrays.sort(). Then retrieve the first item like so:

```
public static int problem4(String s, String t) {
    String[] items = new String[2];
    items[0]=s;
    items[1]=t;
    items.sort();
    return items[0].length();
    
}
```

Or you can use the `.compareTo` method like so:

```
public static int problem4(String s, String t) {
    return s.compareTo(t) > 0 ? t.length() : s.length();
 }
```

Comment: Since sort() makes use of Comparable and Comparable has the method compareTo, why not use that method directly?

Comment: And you can use ternary expression to simplify your code in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Something to this effect should work I think.

```
public static int problem4(String s, String t){
    if (s.compareTo(t)>0)
        System.out.println(t.length());
        return t.length();
    else 
        System.out.println(s.length());
        return s.length();
}

problem("a", "b");
```

Comment: I thought maybe they'd be able to handle the rest of it but I finished it off for good measure